# Python split in a certain pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, split

I have this data

```
1 E1992 RED612 Cat Pinafore Dress Red 6-12 mths 5 5.05 0.00 25.25
```

Using the split command I can only split it like this -

```
['1', 'E1992', 'RED612', 'Cat', 'Pinafore', 'Dress', 'Red', '6-12', 'mths', '5', '5.05', '0.00', '25.25']
```

But I want to split it like this -

```
['1', 'E1992', 'RED612', 'Cat Pinafore Dress Red', '6-12 mths', '5', '5.05', '0.00', '25.25']
```

All of my items in the list are written in this pattern for example -

```
4 E4117 WHI23 White 2-3 yrs 70 4.70 0.00 329.00
4 E4395 RED36Y Stripe Sun Hat Red 3-6 yrs 30 3.20 0.00 96.00
```

And I want to split them in a similar pattern

I wanted to know if it was possible to split them using some regex command or any other command if all the items follow this pattern.

Comment: It looks like it should be possible, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is structural data and it's table-like so you can do like this:

```
line = '1 E1992 RED612 Cat Pinafore Dress Red 6-12 mths 5 5.05 0.00 25.25'
line = line.split()
output = line[:3] + [' '.join(line[3:-6])] + [' '.join(line[-6:-4])] + line[-4:]
```

And your output would be:

```
['1', 'E1992', 'RED612', 'Cat Pinafore Dress Red', '6-12 mths', '5', '5.05', '0.00', '25.25']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have a 3-N-2-4 arrangement of fragments (three pieces, followed by N pieces, followed by 2 pieces, followed by 4 more pieces), you can combine the first, the middle (the combination of all middle pieces), and the last slices:

```
parts = your_string.split()
parts[:3] + [" ".join(parts[3:-6])] \
          + [" ".join(parts[-6:-4])] \
          + parts[-4:]
#['1', 'E1992', 'RED612', 'Cat Pinafore Dress Red', '6-12 mths', '5', '5.05', '0.00', '25.25']
```

P.S. Updated to combine the years/months data. I overlooked that detail earlier.

Comment: Thanks you so much! Yes it worked, I didn't know about this function.